# SDL 2.0 Build Error

Tags: c, linux, gcc, sdl

Apparently, I don't have SDL installed correctly since a sample program I found in some of the tutorials for SDL 2.0 don't buid correctly.

Mind you, I am using Ubuntu 12.04 as my operating system, used the instructions in the source code of SDL 2.0.3 to install it on my OS, am using CodeLite 5.4, and am using C as my programming language.

Here is the code I try to test:

```
#include <SDL2/SDL.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int main(int argn,char **argv)
{
    if(SDL_Init(SDL_INIT_VIDEO) != 0)
    {
        fprintf(stderr,"Could not initialize SDL: %s\n", SDL_GetError());

    }

    printf("SDL Initialized\n");
    SDL_Quit();
    printf("SDL Shutdown\n");
    return 0;
}
```

However, I get this:

```
/bin/sh -c 'make -j 1 -e -f  Makefile'
----------Building project:[ SDL - Debug ]----------
make[1]: Entering directory `/home/user/Documents/Programming/C/SDL'
gcc -o ./Debug/SDL @"SDL.txt" -L.
./Debug/main.o: In function `main':
/home/user/Documents/Programming/C/SDL/main.c:6: undefined reference to `SDL_Init'
/home/user/Documents/Programming/C/SDL/main.c:8: undefined reference to `SDL_GetError'
/home/user/Documents/Programming/C/SDL/main.c:13: undefined reference to `SDL_Quit'
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
make[1]: *** [Debug/SDL] Error 1
make[1]: Leaving directory `/home/user/Documents/Programming/C/SDL'
make: *** [All] Error 2
3 errors, 0 warnings
```

Can someone please explain to me what the issue is and how I can fix it?

Comment: How did you install? Did you get any errors? You can try compiling using terminal `gcc main.cpp -lSDL2 -o Test && ./Test` You can also take a look at this guide : http://cogsandlevers.blogspot.no/2014/01/installing-sdl2-on-linux.html

Comment: I installed it and what I remember it saying was configure.in was outdated or something like that. Thank you, I will look at that guide :)