# SDL 2.0 Build Error(Duplicate)

Tags: c, ubuntu, sdl, sdl-2, codelite

I haven't actually been able to use SDL 2.0 on my laptop, so I am reposting the whole post again. Hopefully somebody else can help me, as I am a little desperate.

"Apparently, I don't have SDL installed correctly since a sample program I found in some of the tutorials for SDL 2.0 don't buid correctly.

Mind you, I am using Ubuntu 12.04 as my operating system, used the instructions in the source code of SDL 2.0.3 to install it on my OS, am using CodeLite 5.4, and am using C as my programming language.

Here is the code I try to test:

```
#include <SDL2/SDL.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int main(int argn,char **argv)
{
    if(SDL_Init(SDL_INIT_VIDEO) != 0)
    {
        fprintf(stderr,"Could not initialize SDL: %s\n", SDL_GetError());

    }

    printf("SDL Initialized\n");
    SDL_Quit();
    printf("SDL Shutdown\n");
    return 0;
}
```

However, I get this:

```
/bin/sh -c 'make -j 1 -e -f  Makefile'
----------Building project:[ SDL - Debug ]----------
make[1]: Entering directory `/home/user/Documents/Programming/C/SDL'
gcc -o ./Debug/SDL @"SDL.txt" -L.
./Debug/main.o: In function `main':
/home/user/Documents/Programming/C/SDL/main.c:6: undefined reference to `SDL_Init'
/home/user/Documents/Programming/C/SDL/main.c:8: undefined reference to `SDL_GetError'
/home/user/Documents/Programming/C/SDL/main.c:13: undefined reference to `SDL_Quit'
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
make[1]: *** [Debug/SDL] Error 1
make[1]: Leaving directory `/home/user/Documents/Programming/C/SDL'
make: *** [All] Error 2
3 errors, 0 warnings
```

Can someone please explain to me what the issue is and how I can fix it?"

Comment: Your problem is with makefile. Add `-lSDL2` to link flags.

Comment: possible duplicate of [SDL 2.0 Build Error](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23172804/sdl-2-0-build-error)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From codelite:
Right click on the active project icon (in the tree view) -> Settings -> Common Settings -> Linker -> Libraries

and add:
`SDL2` (no need to add -l, or .a/.so codelite will fix this for you)

Hit F7 and it should link fine

Eran

Comment: THANK YOU SO MUCH! This is what I needed. I didn't know anything about linker flags and you explained how to add them. Thank you a million times!